# File Share behind Proxy

Tags: proxy, network-shares, file-sharing, shared-folders, smb

My company uses a proxy. Now I want to access a shared folder on a Windows box not located in our network. The users and rights are propery set but it doesn't work. I believe it's because I have to go through the proxy in order to get out of our network. However, I believe I can't configure a proxy for file access, can I? Could a 3rd party tool help me?

(it's currently only a test setup so even a hack would be okay for the moment).

Comment: Depends on the proxy type. Is it a regular HTTP proxy? Do you explicitly set it in your browser settings or is it a transparent proxy?

Comment: I believe it's a regular HTTP proxy. I only set it my browser setings.